# Remote server administration on a large scale

Tags: centos, ssh, redhat, remote-access

I need to remotely manage virtual machines (many of them) via secure channel.  SSH inbound is disabled.  Anyway to use some web based tool running behind SSL.  It will be used to push updates, config changes including execution of shell commands/scripts?

The servers in question would also be in private network but has outbound connectivity with only 443 for inbound access.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure a web-based tool to push updates and run shell commands is going to pass security muster for an organization that's even blocking SSH...

Comment: Is there a VPN? Because if neither VPN nor SSH are available, remote management will be highly problematic.

Comment: Instead of pushing changes, consider VM's to pull the changes from a configuration server: `cfengine` provides such a pull model.

Comment: Blocking ssh is beyond paranoid and verging on insane. Allowing port 443 at the same time, pushes it over the edge.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the n2n peer-to-peer tunneling protocol](http://www.ntop.org/products/n2n/) to help ensure access to remote systems where you can't control the firewalling setup.

I use it for the exact purposes you're planning... in addition, it's useful for remote SNMP polling and OpenNMS.